# Issue on Updating Global Variable Between Classes in Python

Tags: python

Using ArcGIS Python Addin I need to update a global variable called `phase` between classes. Here what I want to do is updating the `phase` variable by changing the `ComboBoxClass1` and accessing to it by click on `ButtonClass3`.

As you can see I tried to pass `global phase = selection` on

```
    def onSelChange(self, selection):
        global phase = selection
```

but looks like this is not working!

```
import arcpy
import pythonaddins
import os

phase = ""

class ButtonClass3(object):
    """Implementation for Trace_addin.button (Button)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.checked = False
    def onClick(self):
        print global phase

class ComboBoxClass1(object):
    """Implementation for Trace_addin.combobox (ComboBox)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = ["Phase A", "Phase B", "Phase C"]
        self.editable = True
        self.enabled = True
        self.dropdownWidth = 'WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW'
        self.width = 'WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW'
    def onSelChange(self, selection):
        global phase = selection
    def onEditChange(self, text):
        pass
    def onFocus(self, focused):
        pass
    def onEnter(self):
        pass
    def refresh(self):
        pass
```

Comment: Can I ask why are you down voting this question?!

Comment: `global phase` is an entire statement.  You cannot combine this with either reading or writing the value of the variable.

Comment: What is your _exact and specific_ question?

Comment: as i said I can not get access to updated phase on click

Comment: SO users downvote because you shown absolutely no understanding of python's `global` syntax, and that your question does not have a clear problem statement ("this is not working" doesn't count). If you done a simple Google search on "how to use global in python", your question could've been much better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @jasonharper said `global phase` is a statement on its own.
If you want to access `phase` you don't have to use `global` eg :

```
print phase
```

If you want to modify `phase` use :

```
global phase
phase = selection
```

Comment: Thanks t.m.adam, I still do not understand why some people vote questions down instead of hinting like what you did!

Comment: I don't know, it is a well written question, maybe they think it's too easy. Don't mind the downvoters..

Comment: @Suffii People often downvote questions that show that you don't know the basic syntax of the language. SO is not supposed to be a tutoring service.